Map is not displaying in android emulator extended controls
Accessing Location tab in Extended controls doesn't load google maps. It's blank instead.
These are the things I tried so far, with no result:
Updated android emulator to the newest 34.1.19 ver.
Updated visual studio
Deleted everything under C:\Users\xxx.android\avd folder and created a new emulator
Tried multiple device's api level, android os version
Cleaning, rebuilding, reloading project/solution/restarting computer
Android manifest does contain necesseary permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

I can access browser inside emulator
Altough it's propably not related, but I'll add that the google maps works just fine inside application.
The problem only appears when I try to mock/set my location via extended controls feature

I had the same issue as you, literally just this morning. I think it's an issue between Google, and the Android Emulator version that's included with the current version of Visual Studio 2022 -- not 100% sure.
That said, I installed the latest preview for the next version of VS2022 (17.11.0), and that worked (after updating the Android SDK/Tools). I assume once that goes live, things will work again, but that might help you work around the issue for the moment, even if you just use the emulator from the preview and continue your work in the stable version.
